# Can I combine selectors like +,~, and >?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just wanted to know whether we can use tree structured statements in CSS  like:

```
a:hover + ul > li{
   .....
}
```

Can I use these in CSS?

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. Any reason to assume you can't? Or do you have restrictions like "it has to run in IE6"?

Comment: have you tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: I tried the same code on the "Navigation Bar menu" example found on w3 site ( link)(http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float_advanced). Please visit this and try the same thing and reply me if it works

Comment: What is the matter? Can't you try it yourself? You refuse to visit W3Schools? You refuse to believe the results you see on the W3Schools site? You're using a very old browser? Javascript disabled, overactive ad blocker, typos in the css you tried, specificity issues?